# Expression of $P_n(0)$ for even $n$?

Tags: polynomials

$P_n(x)$ is legendre Polynomials. 
For odd $n$, it is zero. What is the expression of $P_n(0)$ for even $n$?

Comment: See Wikipedia, there is a recursion formula for $P_n$.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133817/legendre-polynomial-to-show-identity-cant-spot-mistake/1133918#1133918