# Prove that the Legendre polynomial holds true using the generating function and a binomial expansion.

Tags: generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

I tried using that 
$$P_{2n}(z)=\frac1{2^{2n}(2n)!}\frac{d^{2n}}{dz^{2n}}(z^2-1)^{2n} $$
but I am having trouble taking the derivative when $n$ is unknown and $z$ is $0$.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: This is the problem]

Comment: See my answer on another question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133817/legendre-polynomial-to-show-identity-cant-spot-mistake/1133918#1133918